# Codeigniter: Controller signup error

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

This is the controller code for signing up:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Signup extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $data = array(
                'title' => 'SignUp Page'
            );
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('signup');
    }

    public function signup_validation(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('salutation', 'Salutation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fName', 'First Name', 'required|trim|alpha|xss_clean|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lName', 'Last Name', 'required|trim|alpha|xss_clean|strip_tags');
        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $month = $this->input->post('months');
            $day = $this->input->post('days');
            $year = $this->input->post('years');
            $birthday = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|min_length[10]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact No', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|numeric|min_length[8]|max_length[8]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]|xss_clean|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|alpha_numeric|xss_clean|strip_tags|min_length[3]|max_length[20],is_unique[users.username');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[8]|xss_clean|strip_tags|alpha_numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]|xss_clean|strip_tags|alpha_numeric');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            $key = md5(uniqid());

            $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype'=>'html'));
            $this->load->model('model_users');

            $this->email->from('admin@snt.website', "SWAP");
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->subject("Confirm your account.");

            $message = "<p>Thank you for signing up!</p>";
            $message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."main/register_user/$key'>Click Here</a> to confirm your account</p>";

            $this->email->message($message);

            if ($this->model_users->add_temp_users($key, $birthday)){
                if ($this->email->send()){
                    echo "The email has been sent!";
                } else echo "Could not send the mail";
            } else echo "problem adding to database";

        } else {
            $this->index;
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked through my codes and have no idea why does this error keep showing up:
[image]

If i am to remove all the validations it will work perfectly fine.Can someone help me with this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to write:

```
$this->index();
          //^^ So you actually call the function index and not the property
```

instead of:

```
$this->index;
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much got so obsess in the validation forgot to look at the bottom. Thank you! :)